# How to identify array type?

Tags: .net, windbg, il, sos, sosex

I have an OutOfMemoryException and I'd like to analyze the size and the type of the array which shall be created.

I have created a demo purpose dump for that situation and I'm able to get the following information:

```
0:000> !pe
Exception object: 023f389c
Exception type: System.OutOfMemoryException
Message: <none>
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    0015EE44 0099007F OOM2!OOM2.Program.Main()+0xf

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 8007000e

0:000> !u 0099007F 
Normal JIT generated code
OOM2.Program.Main()
Begin 00990070, size 22
00990070 baffffff7f      mov     edx,7FFFFFFFh
00990075 b90241a478      mov     ecx,offset mscorlib_ni+0x4102 (78a44102)
0099007a e8192194ff      call    002d2198 (JitHelp: CORINFO_HELP_NEWARR_1_VC)
>>> 0099007f 8bc8            mov     ecx,eax
...
```

So I can see that a new array is created and the size is 7FFFFFFF, which is 2 billion items. (Please ignore the fact that you can't even create a byte[] of that size in a 32 bit .NET application, so in this example the type would probably not matter at all.)

I have now read that the type of the array is in the ECX register, but unfortunately `mscorlib_ni+0x4102 (78a44102)` isn't very helpful.

I have tried `!mln`, `!mdt` and even unrealistic `!ip2mt`, but none of them displays the expected `byte` or `byte[]` output. Is there a way of getting the type from that native image of mscorlib?

Comment: The array type is indeed being passed in ECX. However, rather than a regular metadata token, it is a `handle to a metadata token`. This is generated by the JIT. I am unaware of a way to go from a handle to the original metadata token. Rather, since the IL exists, it is easier to view it to identify the array type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to dump the IL corresponding to the method that the array is being created in.

First, use `!clrstack` to get the method you're in.  In my case I'm in a dummy app in the `Main` method:

```
0:000> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x7d0 (0)
Child SP       IP Call Site
0016f094 758dc42d [HelperMethodFrame: 0016f094] 
0016f120 003200af ConsoleApplication4.Program.Main(System.String[]) [c:\Users\smt\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Program.cs @ 215]
0016f2bc 743b3de2 [GCFrame: 0016f2bc]
```

Next use `!name2ee` to get the method desc of this method (the next command needs it):

```
0:000> !name2ee ConsoleApplication4!ConsoleApplication4.Program.Main
Module:      00282eac
Assembly:    ConsoleApplication4.exe
Token:       0600013c
MethodDesc:  00283dbc
Name:        ConsoleApplication4.Program.Main(System.String[])
JITTED Code Address: 00320050
```

Now, dump the IL of the method:

```
0:000> !dumpil 00283dbc
ilAddr = 002d4bc4
IL_0000: nop 
IL_0001: newobj class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<??????  ??????n?.::.ctor 
IL_0006: stloc.0 
IL_0007: br.s IL_001e
IL_0009: nop 
IL_000a: ldc.i4 2147483647
IL_000f: newarr System.Single
IL_0014: stloc.1 
IL_0015: ldloc.0 
IL_0016: ldloc.1 
IL_0017: callvirt class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<??????  ??????N?.::Add 
IL_001c: nop 
IL_001d: nop 
IL_001e: ldc.i4.1 
IL_001f: stloc.2 
IL_0020: br.s IL_0109
```

For comparison, this is my method in C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<float[]> arrays = new List<float[]>();
    while (true)
    {
        float[] f = new float[Int32.MaxValue];
        arrays.Add(f);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You can see on line IL_000f that a new array of type `System.Single` is being created.

---

I went down this road because I can't decipher the argument being passed to the actual native method that creates the array.  If you run `kb` at the point the exception is thrown:

```
0:000> kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0016efa4 74502a42 e0434352 00000001 00000005 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
0016f048 745d55ef 00000000 bc1d0b3d 0016f10c clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x276
0016f078 7464ae51 bc1d0a7d 0016f150 00000000 clr!UnwindAndContinueRethrowHelperAfterCatch+0x83
0016f118 003200af 00000000 02202480 00000000 clr!JIT_NewArr1+0x1af
0016f138 743b3de2 00720198 0016f198 743c3315 0x3200af
0016f144 743c3315 0016f1dc 0016f188 74502c66 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x34
...
```

You can see that `clr!JIT_NewArr1` is being called, which creates a one-dimensional array.  To do that, [it needs the type and the size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490266/1698557).  These arguments are copied into `ecx` and `edx`, respectively:

```
0:000> !u 003200AF 
...
003200a0 b9e2302a73      mov     ecx,offset mscorlib_ni+0x30e2 (732a30e2)
003200a5 baffffff7f      mov     edx,7FFFFFFFh
003200aa e89121f5ff      call    00272240 (JitHelp: CORINFO_HELP_NEWARR_1_VC)
>>> 003200af 8945e8          mov     dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax
003200b2 8b45e8          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-18h]
003200b5 8945f0          mov     dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax
...
```

As you can see, `ecx` gets `732a30e2`, which somehow maps to the type information for `System.Single`, but I can't figure out how...