# How to dump and analyze a c#process?

Tags: c#, memory, dump

I've made a c# apps which is normally around 40Mb RAM usage, but for some reason after 1 day or 2 crash with out of memory exception... What i'd like is to see what is using all the memory, but the problem is that I use Visual Studio 2015 and I can't really leave the debugger running because the process Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe is eating all my memory... I tried to let the program crash and attach VS debugger afterwards, but it just hanged forever... So I'd like to get some help to know how can I dump my process when it goes out of memory and see what is using the mem to eventually figure out why ??

---

So after letting VS running for 1hour it eventually finished memory dump, turns out the culprit seems:
ThreadPoolWorkQueue+QueueSegment    249,928 263,922,932 283,922,912
QueueUserWorkItemCallback   999,999 19,999,980  19,999,980

Looks like I am not correctly dequeuing objects from a ConcurrentQueue class. I will investigate.

Comment: You should start the program, make a snapshot and then let it run for 1 or 2 hours and then take another snapshot. This shouldn't eat up all your memory. Afterwards you can do a comparision between both snapshots. It would be helpful if you would provide some information about your program. Maybe the comm can help you identifying the memory leak.

Comment: Have you tried generating a minidump with a tool such as ProcessExplorer ?

Comment: The problem is that the soft will say at 40Mb for hours, and then at some point it start leaking, so getting dump at start won't help; For process Explorer tool, how can I see what my process is uing as memory / class instances ?
PS: My program is a forex trading robot, so maybe something from the market is triggering the issue, but I was not able to recreate by trying to open/close/modify trades, which I believe might be the trigger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I take a good crash dump for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net)

Comment: Related: [How to use WinDbg to track down .NET out of memory exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142607/how-to-use-windbg-to-track-down-net-out-of-memory-exceptions/26150591#26150591)