# How to manually crash c# code

Tags: c#

I am facing lot of issue to exe crash on production server however I want to dump file when exe crash with detail log.

I have found procdump tool. Can you suggest code c# which manually crash exe, so can check what kind of information get in dump log.

Comment: `throw new Exception();` <= and then do not catch the exception anywhere down the call stack.

Comment: Raise exception? Load an other platform assembly (x86/x64)

Comment: What kind of crash are you looking for?

Comment: FYI: [How do I take a good crash dump for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net/24874028#24874028)

Comment: I am getting out of memory exception and exe break down on server, so looking forward to dump all information how many objects are loaded and its state.

Comment: Then see also: [How to use WinDbg to track down .NET out of memory exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142607/how-to-use-windbg-to-track-down-net-out-of-memory-exceptions/26150591#26150591)

Answer (score 5):

A crash is caused by an exception which is not caught. Just throw one in your code

```
throw new Exception();
```

and do not add a try-catch block anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The best, which can't be caught, is creating a stack overflow exception. This one will fall thru the try/catches...

```
void MyMethod()
{
    MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: When built in __Release__ configuration (optimizations enabled), this should not crash (due to [tail-call optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail-call_optimization)).

Comment: can you substantiate this?

Comment: When built that way, the run-time will choose to optimize things by not creating a new "frame" on the call stack for each recursion, so this will become similar to `here: goto here;` or `while (true) { }` neither of which will crash the application. It is easy to verify by pasting your code into Visual Studio, be sure to have "Release" in the Solution Configurations drop-down, and then run without debugging (Ctrl+F5), for example.

Comment: Thanks for the info. With that info i would use the debug build for this test.

Comment: Correction: In fact I could not corroborate my own claim, following my own instructions above. I was quite sure I tried this earlier with success. Maybe it was changed in some (recent) version of the CLR, or maybe it depends on the hardware or some additional setting that I am not aware of.