# How the CLR implements IEnumerable<T> on Arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

I realize that arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>` "at run time". According to the [MSDN docs for Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays *at run time*, and as a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class.

Of course, this is correct. In looking at the source code for `Array` you'll see it implements the non-generic version of `IEnumerable` only.

If you run the below snippet of code you will see the type of the generic `Enumerator` is of type `` System.SZArrayHelper+SZGenericArrayEnumerator`1[System.String] ``.

```
String[] array = new[] { "Apple", "Banana", "Grape" };
IEnumerator enumer = ((IEnumerable<String>)array).GetEnumerator();

// Next line writes: System.SZArrayHelper+SZGenericArrayEnumerator`1[System.String]
Console.WriteLine(enumer.GetType());
```

I was hoping someone might be able to provide some insight as to *how* the CLR implements `IEnumerable<T>` at run time? What's the mechanism that makes it happen? Is something hard-coded in the CLR or is there something in the `Array` class that informs the CLR to dynamically implement the generic version?

As a follow up, I was reading "C# 5,0 in a Nutshell" and on page 274 the authors claim that the `Array` class must implement the non-generic version of `IEnumerable` for "backward compatibility". Could someone offer an example of the necessity this for "backward compatibility"?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I don't have documentation to cite but I'm pretty sure it will be hard-coded into the CLI to handle Array as a special case.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489661/whats-the-magic-of-arrays-in-c-sharp which may be even considered duplicate of your question.

Comment: It comes with the implementation of `IList<T>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163297/how-do-arrays-in-c-sharp-partially-implement-ilistt